# Linux - HTPASSWD file too big? (more than 2000 users)

Tags: performance, authentication, debian, .htpasswd, dbm

I got here a quite huge HTPASSWD file which stores the users and their encrypted passwords. This file is used to authenticate users using HTTP.

I got more than 2000 entries (users) in this file. The size of that file is 116KB.

[image: screenshot of the htpasswd file via putty]

Additionnaly, about 40 new entries are added in this file each day.

So I would like to know if I got a problem with an htpasswd file that big. And what are my alternatives to the htpasswd file? And how can I transfer my users and their encrypted passwords to the new alternative?

**SOLUTION**

I figured out how to convert my htpasswd file to the DBM format using this perl script: [htpasswd2dbm.pl](http://www.apacheweek.com/issues/htpasswd2dbm.pl)

Here is how to use it:

```
htpasswd2dbm.pl -htpasswd users usersdbm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is perfomance issues related to large htpasswd files. However you can use DBM format to improve performance for large password files:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth_dbm.html#authdbmuserfile

A quick google provided this page which gives a good overview of using DBM files:

http://www.apacheweek.com/features/dbmauth

Comment: What do I do with my current users and their encrypted passwords? How can I transfer these to the DBM format? I CANNOT retrieve their password in clear.

Comment: That is covered towards the bottom of the apacheweek link, you can use perl (or similar) to create the dbm file _from_ the htpasswd file. The DBM file uses a key/value pairs, where the value would be the "hashed" password for that users. The example script given is: http://www.apacheweek.com/issues/htpasswd2dbm.pl

Comment: Thanks Drav, I figured it out.

Comment: No problem! A vote on my answer would be appreciated :) thanks!